# Impossible to make logitech cam work skype

Tags: skype

I have installed skype 4.1 in ubuntu 12.04 but unfortunately I cannot make the logitech cam work as a microphone. I have tried all sorts of things pulse audio skype options but nothing works. What can I do i am desparate...I attach pics of the pulseaudio and skype audio options!

[image]/i.stack.imgur.com/oiRHu.png

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like a weak answer but I had the same problem with my Logitech cam with Skype. All I did was make sure all input/output devices were turned up all the way and then relaunched Skype did a test call with "echo" in Skype and it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion didn't help. Any other ideas?